# Add to SQLAlchemy Session in before_flush event?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a proper way to add new object to Session while in before_flush event without infinite loop?

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(SomeSessionOrFactory, 'before_flush')
def receive_before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    session.add(NEW_OBJECT)
```